# Picking the right inductor

Tags: power, inductor

I am trying to design my first PFC (power factor correction), and I am looking for the right inductor, but all the datasheets I've seen so far have the inductance rated at 1 kHz or 100 kHz. My question is, how do i calculate the actual inductance at the frequency I am using? Thank you

Comment: Please explain acronyms used and link to datasheets for any parts referenced. It may help if you tell us what frequency you are aiming for. Welcome to EE.SE.

Comment: Private first class (PFC) is, I believe, a relatively low rank in the US Army.

Comment: I thought it was perfect fried chicken or parallel flange channel or even perfluorocarbons, but no, it turns out to be power factor correction in a switch mode power supply :(

Comment: PFC: power factor correction, part of a AC-DC power supply.

Comment: I don't have a specific part in mind yet, but I am using 500kHz - 1MHz. Depending on the available inductor.

Answer (score 1):

The inductance of a switch mode power inductor is commonly specified at 100KHz and with a tolerance of around 20%. From what I have seen, the deviation due to frequency up to 100MHz or so is small enough that with the design just taking account of the 20% or so tolerance is good enough.

Some inductor datasheets may give a graph of inductance vs frequency, or impedance vs frequency. That can confirm the validity of the above assumption.

By the way, the specification of 100KHz is based on a sine wave. So whether the switching frequency is 100KHz or 1MHz, the switching waveform contains harmonics with multiples of the base frequency. Therefore you can never operate an inductor in a typical switch mode design at exactly just a particular frequency (sine wave) anyway.

Comment: Minor typos: KHz = kelvin-hertz. kHz = kilo-hertz. For SI units named after a person the abbreviation is capitalized and the full unit name is lower case. V for volt, A for amp, H for henry, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Many datasheets will have a graph of inductance vs frequency.  You can read the inductance at your working frequency from the graph.

An example of this type of graph is shown on page 4 of the IHLP inductor series datasheet.

http://www.vishay.com/docs/34316/ihlp3232dz01.pdf